# Show all CSS styles for an element, even when not currently matching media query

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

Is there a way (preferably in Chrome Developer Tools) to see all CSS styles that apply to a certain element?

The *Styles* tab in Chrome Devtools only shows rules whose media queries currently match.

Comment: this maybe helpfull
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

Comment: @MalithMcR I don't see it, sorry. Which section are you referring to?

Comment: I think use responsive view to see media queries.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/device-testing/devtools-emulator


 also this extension will little help to see'em.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-inspector/memcdolmmnmnleeiodllgpibdjlkbpim?hl=en

Comment: you can see them if they've already  been overridden, don't think there is a way to see the ones that haven't been elaborated yet through dev-tools

Comment: @AndreKR interesting question - I also asked myself how to get all the responsive styles, but never found the "right" way to do it. Currently I'm resizing the browser window to see what styles would be applied, which is just wrong, IMHO. Or looking at the source file and searching for the required selector.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

You can simply click on element tab and then  on you stylesheet document link, it will take you to the Source tab where you can easily edit you stylesheet and can see you styles already given in the stylesheet.

[image]

Comment: The "style.css:308" (red circle in your screenshot) doesn't appear for styles that are inactive because of a media query.

Answer (score -4):

I think you mean the "Compute" tab next to it.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles

Comment: Nope, even the compute tab doesn't show styles when they are inactive because of media queries.